# Open UWP Window from WPF

Tags: wpf, uwp

I have two projects configured in  UWP and another is in WPF. Due to some reason, I can not ignore this architecture.
Now I want to open a previously open UWP window once I will close WPF window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between UWP and Non UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182643/communication-between-uwp-and-non-uwp-app)

Comment: Hi, you can create a `Protocol` for a UWP app and evoke a UWP app with a URI when the WPF app is closed. Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using RequestInfoForPackageAsync() API of windows.

1. I have to save the UWP App package family name on the launch of the UWP app.(Use 
   Package API for this)
   2- Now from WPF call RequestInfoForPackageAsync and start the app. Then need to manage the 
   start the event as required.
   If anyone know better way to handle this please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate between UWP and non-uwp apps using [AppServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) , this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182643/communication-between-uwp-and-non-uwp-app) is talking about the same scenario .

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi I am able to send uwp window in suspend state. Now WPF Window is opened. Now on the close of WPF window user, UWP Window(which is in suspended state) should resume.r u saying we can achieve using App service?If yes please explain or suggest a link.